# How to google authenticate with fire-base in react-native project?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using [Social Auth](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/master/auth/social-auth)! plugin to sign in with google using firebase and I have followed all the steps according to the document.
my code is :

```
import { GoogleSignin } from 'react-native-google-signin';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'



export async function googleLogin() {
  try {
    // add any configuration settings here:
    await GoogleSignin.configure();

    const data = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

    // create a new firebase credential with the token
    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(data.idToken, data.accessToken)
    // login with credential
    const firebaseUserCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);

    console.warn(JSON.stringify(firebaseUserCredential.user.toJSON()));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

when I running app in android device,
the react native debugger showing me this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
    at DeltaPatcher.applyDelta (DeltaPatcher.js:77)
    at deltaUrlToBlobUrl (deltaUrlToBlobUrl.js:28)
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. or there is some problem in react-native plugin

Comment: You are doing await in function, so method should be `async`.

Comment: please check my edited question now, it was like this in the document, but still facing the same issue